# HDD speed is very slow on Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04

I have two operating systems one of them is Ubuntu it was working well till today it was booting very slow and I can't open anything after it boots I investigated and the reading speed was like 47 kibps!! Though in windows it's up to 30 mbps and I have no idea what is happening
Note: every thing works well in emergency mode but once I login it starts to slow down